# VS2017: Multiple typescript folders; TFS source control; and publishing to IIS

Tags: visual-studio, typescript, iis, tfs, visual-studio-2017

I am working with a Solution which contains many Projects. One project, which is an ASP.Net MVC project, contains two folders inside `~/Scripts` which have TypeScript files.

```
~/Scripts/TSProj1/typescript/Main.ts
~/Scripts/TSProj1/typescript/Sub1.ts
~/Scripts/TSProj1/typescript/Sub2.ts
~/Scripts/TSProj1/tsProj1.js
~/Scripts/TSProj1/tsProj1.js.map
~/Scripts/TSProj2/typescript/Main.ts
~/Scripts/TSProj2/typescript/Sub1.ts
~/Scripts/TSProj2/typescript/Sub2.ts
~/Scripts/TSProj2/tsProj1.js
~/tsconfig.json
```

Previously, I only had a single TypeScript sub-project and it was alright, but ever since I introduced the second, there have been **a number** of issues for me and my team. I really need a solution for this.

Now, I know that currently Visual Studio [does not support](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3645) multiple `tsconfig.json` files, nor does `tsconfig.json` support [multiple configurations](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3645#issuecomment-221773972).

Just as a band-aid solution for myself, I have both configurations in my `tsconfig.json` file, and one of them is always commented out:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outFile": "Scripts/TSProj1/tsProj1.js"
  },
  "files": [
    "Scripts/TSProj1/typescript/Main.ts",
    "Scripts/TSProj1/typescript/Sub1.ts",
    "Scripts/TSProj1/typescript/Sub2.ts"
  ],
  "compileOnSave": true
}
/*
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outFile": "Scripts/TSProj2/tsProj2.js"
  },
  "files": [
    "Scripts/TSProj2/typescript/Main.ts",
    "Scripts/TSProj2/typescript/Sub1.ts",
    "Scripts/TSProj2/typescript/Sub2.ts"
  ],
  "compileOnSave": true
}
*/
```

and I can comment/uncomment depending on which sub-project I want to build at the time. For a while, I thought this was working, but now I seem to also be getting compilation errors on the TypeScript code whose `tsconfig.json` entry is commented out. Yet another band-aid solution for now is to exclude the `.ts` files from the project during compilation.

I need some sort of workable solution for this, however. It's causing a lot of problems for me, but especially so for the other people who are also working on this solution.

I mentioned there were a number of problems I'm experiencing:

- As I said, I need to be able to compile multiple **separate** TypeScript folders. Commenting out a section of `tsconfig.json` seemed to work, but now, mysteriously, it no longer does, and the sub-project not included in `tsconfig.json` now gives compilation errors.
- Often, compilation does not produce a new `.js` file. I suspect this is because Visual Studio has, for whatever reason, checked the file out and set it as read-only. I noticed that when I open a command prompt, `tsc.exe` complains that it cannot write to the output `.js` file. Sometimes this also happens with the source map. To fix this, I delete the `.js` and `.js.map` files, but I shouldn't have to.
- When publishing, I've noticed that the `.js` files are not pushed through to the web server. I've been manually copying the file across. I don't know why this is, since the `.js` file is part of the project.

I suspect some of these issues could be related to nesting (or lack thereof). For example, a SASS file will have a corresponding `.css` file nested underneath, and the `.css.min` file nested underneath that. This makes Visual Studio understand these files are related and it behaves accordingly. Possibly Visual Studio should be told that the `.js.map` file belongs to the `.js` file, and that the `.js` file corresponds to the typescript source. I'm not sure how to achieve this.

I really need solutions for these issues. They don't necessarily need to be convenient for me, but they definitely shouldn't affect the others in the team. I don't mind if the solution is somehow to call `tsc.exe` from the command-line manually, but checking-in to TFS and publishing must work.

Thank you. I will be so grateful if this can be sorted out.

Comment: What's the mean of checking-in to TFS must work? If it's not working on the local side in VS, TFS build is just calling msbuild command in local, it should also fail. You are still facing the issue of  compiling multiple separate TypeScript folders. This issue seems not related to TFS.

Comment: I am having a number of issues related to source control, typescript, and publishing: The `.js` and `.js.map` files are constantly marked as read-only, so I cannot run `tsc.exe` to manually compile my TS when VS fails to compile it. I have removed the read-only flag and compiled, and the changes are not written to source control. I have managed to successfully compile a TS directory and created a `.js` and `.js.map` file, which work fine when debugging locally. When I publish to IIS on another machine, the `.js` and `.js.map` files are not pushed across even thought they're in the solution.